# Tried to make USB stick from OS X

Tags: live-usb, directory, macbook-pro

When trying to make a USB stick for Mac I got this error:

```
MacBookPro-UserName:~ UserName$ hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o ~/ubuntu/USB-Overdrive-302.img ~/ubuntu/ubuntu.iso
hdiutil: convert failed - No such file or directory
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Add more details and you will get better responses

Comment: Most likely there is no ~/ubuntu/ubuntu.iso what does $> ls ~/ubuntu/ubuntu.iso say?

Answer (score 5):

You're showing a file missing, which indicates the command had the wrong path to the `.iso` file

We are only using *hdiutil* to convert the Ubuntu ISO to an IMG format which mac can use.

Use the *hdiutil* command to convert the `.iso` to an IMG file in a directory on your hard drive.

Then use the *dd* command to actually copy the files over.

[How to install Ubuntu on MacBook using USB Stick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick)

Make sure you have the paths right - the tip to drag and drop the file or copy and paste the file into the terminal window is a good one:  It will give you the exact location, not a relative one.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o <distnation-name> <source-name>
```

This worked for me. Note that the destination comes before the source.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong syntax. Move the input file name to first argument,

so it's `convert input.iso -format UDRW -o output.iso`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about what's on the drive, USB boot sticks can be created on most unix based systems without any extra software just run from terminal:

```
dd if=/path/to/ubuntu.iso of=/dev/usbdevice
```

It works like a charm but **THIS WILL DELETE ANYTHING ON THE USB DEVICE**. Also make sure that the path to the actually usb device, not a partition. For example if the usb device was `sdb` you might see a primary partition, `sdb1` in `/dev`. `of=/dev/sdb1` will not work. You must write to the actually usb device with `of=/dev/sdb` or the usb device will not be recognized as a boot disk.

When you want to use the usb device for anything else, you can make a partition with the remaining space and it will still function as a boot disk or you can reformat the entire disk and use it again for whatever purpose. `dd` is a real gem that is often overlooked. Keep it simple.

Comment: To add to dwrad's post, u might need to add sudo before, like so… `sudo dd if=/Users/marcel/Downloads/ubuntu64.iso of=/dev/disk2`